# background image not reading only in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Yes the below is closed, it's just nested within SASS so the relevant piece pasted below:

```
.greenBox {
    background: url('../images/background_bubble.png'); // ignored only in IE
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    transition: .2s; 
    color: #FFF; 
    width: 310px; 
    height: 137px;
    position: relative; 
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    display: inline-block;
    *//
```

**Update**:

So also just tried:

```
.greenBox {
    background: url('../images/background_bubble.png') no-repeat; // this line
```

No luck. Yes the styles are closed

Comment: Your css incomplete?

Comment: No, i mentioned this is not about closing the bracket within the selector. 100% not the issue. I just don't want to paste all of my code nested within.greenBox here.

Comment: Display block instead maybe?

Comment: Which version of IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try adding a space there on the background-repeat line... IE can be super picky

.greenBox {
        background: url('../images/background_bubble.png'); // ignored only in IE
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        transition: .2s; 
        color: #FFF; 
        width: 310px; 
        height: 137px;
        position: relative; 
        overflow:hidden;
        z-index: 2;
        display: inline-block;
        *//
```

Comment: Try changing background to
background-image: url('../images/background_bubble.png');

Comment: I think background with repeat not in the shorthand can confuse IE.

Comment: Should matter, and space either :p try `background-size:cover;` see what happens. Even better make an online fiddle to test